Слитное и раздельное написание кратких прилагательных и частицы "не"
Несколько раз перечитали правило, так и не можем понять, как лучше написать краткое прилагательное с частицей "не".
У клиента после оказанной услуги спрашиваем, доволен ли он качеством нашей работы. Два варианта ответа" доволен и не(?)доволен.
Как в этом случае пишется "не" и "доволен"?

Оба варианта возможны, вам нужно выбрать самим. Что вы хотите услышать: просто не доволен или категорически недоволен.  Но лучше выбрать более мягкую форму — не доволен.
Ответы Справочной службы
№281414. "НЕ ДОВОЛЕН чем-то" может быть написано раздельно, если важно отрицание факта удовлетворения. "НЕДОВОЛЕН чем-то" пишется слитно, если выражается категорическое неудовлетворение. Верны ли мои рассуждения? ОТВЕТ. Да, верны.
№282196. Как правильно писать: не доволен своей внешностью или недоволен своей внешностью? И почему?
ОТВЕТ
Оба варианта возможны. Раздельное написание (не доволен) подчеркивает отрицание.

Доволен, не доволен, недоволен!

Очень недоволен,  предельно разочарован, дальше сленг.

Недоволен и пишет в жалобную книгу.
